# How to return a sorted array of the elements of an array, but only if they are substrings of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, include

This is a Kata exercise from [codewars.com](https://codewars.com):

> Given two arrays of strings a1 and a2 return a sorted array r in
> lexicographical order of the strings of a1 which are substrings of
> strings of a2.

Example 1:

```
a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
```

returns ["arp", "live", "strong"]

Example 2:

```
a1 = ["tarp", "mice", "bull"]
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
```

returns []"""

This is my code so far (I guess something does not work with line 4 ("if (a2.includes(a1[i]))"):

```
function inArray(a1,a2){
  let r =[];
  for (let i =0; i> a1.length; i++){
    if (a2.includes(a1[i])){
      r.push(a1[i])
    }
  }
  r = r.sort()
  return r
}
```

Comment: `I guess something does not work with line 4 ("if (a2.includes(a1[i]))"` What led you to this conclusion?

Comment: If i visualize the execution on pythontutor.com, which can also visualize javascript ES6, the execution jumps from line 3 (for-loop) directly to line 8 (r=r.sort()) and kinda ignores everything between

Comment: `i >  a1.length;` *might* have something to do with it.

Comment: oh boy, yeah that should be the other way round

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for substrings of the second array.

This solution features array methods

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting a subset of the given array,
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), for a check if some (literately) item match a condition,
- [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for sorting by string or with a callback for a custom sorting.

Beside this, it takes [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), which checks if a string is included in another string. This method is available for arrays to check if an item exists ([`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)), too.

The function is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which allows a short design without having (it could as well) a function body and returns the result without a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). If you take the function body, it needs a return statement, ir required.

```js
const
    inArray = (array1, array2) => a
        .filter(word => array2.some(checkword => checkword.includes(word)))
        .sort();


console.log(inArray(["arp", "live", "strong"], ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"])); // ["arp", "live", "strong"]
console.log(inArray(["tarp", "mice", "bull"], ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"])); // []
```

Comment: could you explain that solution a little? I am relatively new to this and for example do not know what v or w means in this context or what the "some" keywoard does. thank you for your time <3